# detect pause and 'done' button's click on iphone for jwplayer7

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, jwplayer, jwplayer7

How can I detect pause and 'done' buttons's click on iphone, when video plays within native player ? Need to detect this for jwplayer cause am using this player for videos. I did research, checked this [With an HTML5 video element on the iphone, how can I detect the difference between "pause" and "done"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112150/with-an-html5-video-element-on-the-iphone-how-can-i-detect-the-difference-betwe) but it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event listener for the done button. When the player is not fullscreen and in a paused or idle playback state, the user is no longer watching video:

```
jwplayer().getFullscreen() // returns false

jwplayer().getState() // returns "paused" or "idle"
```

You could try listening for the fullscreen event and checking the state:

```
jwplayer().on('fullscreen', function(e) {
    console.log('fullscreen changed:', e.fullscreen, 'state:', this.getState());
});
```

For the paused button, prior to version 7.2 jwplayer did not forward paused events from the video tag. This issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues/834).

```
jwplayer().on('pause', function(e) {
    console.log('paused fullscreen:', this.getFullscreen());
});
```